# Error creating Satellite images from THREDDS server after MetPy 0.12->1.1 upgrade

Tags: python, metpy

Upgraded MetPy to 1.1 and my ability to produce satellite images from a THREDDS server is no longer working. I isolated the part that is causing me issues.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import metpy
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
cat_e = TDSCatalog('https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/satellite/goes/east/products/CloudAndMoistureImagery/FullDisk/Channel09/current/catalog.xml')
nc_e = cat_e.datasets[0].remote_access(use_xarray=True)
data_e = nc_e.metpy.parse_cf('Sectorized_CMI')
```

yields the following output/error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 785, in _rebuild_coords
    var = var.metpy.convert_coordinate_units(coord_name, 'meters')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 190, in convert_coordinate_units
    data=self._data_array[coord].metpy.unit_array.m_as(units)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 386, in m_as
    return self.to(units).magnitude
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 591, in to
    magnitude = self._convert_magnitude_not_inplace(other, *contexts, **ctx_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 540, in _convert_magnitude_not_inplace
    return self._REGISTRY.convert(self._magnitude, self._units, other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/registry.py", line 925, in convert
    return self._convert(value, src, dst, inplace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/registry.py", line 1762, in _convert
    return super()._convert(value, src, dst, inplace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/registry.py", line 1376, in _convert
    return super()._convert(value, src, dst, inplace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pint/registry.py", line 958, in _convert
    raise DimensionalityError(src, dst, src_dim, dst_dim)
pint.errors.DimensionalityError: Cannot convert from 'microradian' (dimensionless) to 'meter' ([length])

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/home/met_scheduler/scripts/satellite/satellite_metpy11.py", line 8, in <module>
    data_e = nc_e.metpy.parse_cf('Sectorized_CMI')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 774, in parse_cf
    var = self._rebuild_coords(var, crs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 797, in _rebuild_coords
    var = var.assign_coords(coords={coord_name: new_coord_var})
  File "/data/home/met_scheduler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/common.py", line 349, in assign_coords
    data.coords.update(results)
  File "/data/home/met_scheduler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/coordinates.py", line 90, in update
    priority_arg=1, indexes=self.indexes)
  File "/data/home/met_scheduler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py", line 362, in merge_coords
    expanded = expand_variable_dicts(aligned)
  File "/data/home/met_scheduler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/merge.py", line 222, in expand_variable_dicts
    var = as_variable(var, name=name)
  File "/data/home/met_scheduler/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/variable.py", line 96, in as_variable
    "variable %r has invalid type %r" % (name, type(obj)))
TypeError: variable 'coords' has invalid type <class 'dict'>
```

I appreciate any thoughts on how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that your Python installation with MetPy is correct? I was able to run your code fine on my local install of MetPy 1.1.0 with Python 3.9. Also, your traceback shows Python 3.6 being used; MetPy 1.1.0 only supports Python >=3.7. You should not have been able to install MetPy 1.1.0 with that version of Python.

You can confirm the version of MetPy being used by adding the following to your script:

```
print(metpy.__version__)
```